# Como puedo hacer que una entrada quede siempre arriba MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
vengo a pedir su ayuda, estoy programando un foro en php y mysql sin framework, y necesito poner en la lista de entradas las reglas del foro de manera que quede fija (SIEMPRE ARRIBA) y así cuando los usuarios vallan ingresando nuevas entradas aparezcan debajo, como en wordpress, espero me haga entender. No me imagino como hacerlo, pido su orientación. Gracias a todos

(LA LINEA ROJA ES SOLO PARA SEÑALAR LA FILA QUE QUIERO QUE QUEDE ARRIBA)

Comment: Podrías colocar un campo llamado "sticky" con valor por defecto "0" en la tabla de entradas y al realizar la query, en la consulta ORDER BY colocar que se ordene primero por esa columna en orden DESC y luego por tus otros criterios. Luego simplemente coloca el valor de sticky a 1 para la entrada que te interesa. Para algo más concreto no estaría mal ver los ejemplos de código y DB que tienes.

Comment: Con Order by de MySQL no te sirve?

Comment: intenta de esta forma: _SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY id_nota;_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> necesito poner en la lista de entradas las reglas del foro de manera
>   que quede fija (SIEMPRE ARRIBA)

Podrías tener un campo en la tabla donde manejas los registros asociados a esas categorías. Llamemos a este campo **"prioridad"**. Para poder realizar el **ORDER BY**
de **MySql** y que cuando traiga los resultados te coloque de primero el registro asociado a "Bienvenido::: Reglas del Foro!" (tendrá prioridad con valor "1" actuando como si fuese una especie de **estatus** mientras que todo lo demas tendrá valor "0")

> y así cuando los usuarios vallan ingresando nuevas entradas aparezcan
>   debajo

Imagino tienes un **campo de "fecha"** que registra el momento en que el usuario creó la entrada, de no ser así, sería bueno que lo tengas porque es el que utilizaremos para que una vez fijo "Bienvenido::: Reglas del Foro!" las demás entradas sean listadas según este campo de **más recientes a los más antiguos** (otra vez utilizamos **ORDER BY** pero en base al campo "fecha")

Aquí te dejo la consulta de ejemplo que deberías utilizar para lograr tu objetivo:

```
$consulta= "SELECT * FROM foro ORDER BY prioridad, fecha DESC";
```